# Conditional Observable Tranformation

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable

Is there a way of performing a conditional Observable transformation or a way of returning the original Observable inside a `.flatMap()`?

The following code will execute `get() : Observable<T>;`. If the value inside the Observable returned by `get()` is not null this Observable should be returned by `getOrFetch()`. If this value is `null` it should return the observable in `fetcher()`.

```js
getOrFetch(fetcher: () => Observable<T>) : Observable<T> {
  let observable : Observable<T> = this.get()
    .flatMap(res => {
      if(res === null) return fetcher();
      else return Observable.of(res);
    }

  observable.do(() => console.log('This code does not execute :(');

  return observable;
}
```

The issue that I am having is that I'm wrapping the value from `get()` each time into a new Observable. Is there a way to avoid this?

Update

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong with it. You want to avoid using `Observable.of`?

Comment: Yes. Can't I just return the original observable instead of creating a new one for every single check against null?

Comment: are you subscribing to your method?

Comment: Of course I am. The problem I'm having is that the observable I'm subscribing to is different than the observable originating from `this.get()`